# How to avoid joining tables in MySQL request

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a report table with 3 columns: total count for the day, the count of `pt_scanid` **which are totaly unique for the table** and the date of the day.

Here is table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners_scanstracking` (
`pt_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pt_partner_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
`pt_ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`pt_scanid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`pt_fn` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`pt_url` mediumtext,
`pt_created` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pt_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

And here is the request I've created:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `c`.`pt_created`) AS `count`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT `x`.`pt_scanid`) AS `uniq`,
       `c`.`pt_created`
FROM `partners_scanstracking` c
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT `x`.*
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM `partners_scanstracking`
      WHERE `pt_partner_id` = '0'
      ORDER BY `pt_created` ASC) x
   GROUP BY `pt_scanid`) x ON DATE(`c`.`pt_created`)=DATE(`x`.`pt_created`)
WHERE (DATE(`c`.`pt_created`) >= '2016-10-06'
       AND DATE(`c`.`pt_created`) <= '2016-12-14')
  AND `c`.`pt_partner_id` = '0'
GROUP BY DATE(`c`.`pt_created`)
ORDER BY `c`.`pt_created` ASC
```

[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMsU.png)

Everything was working great before, but now the table has 500.000 records and request is too slow. I guess that the main reason is that I'm joining two big tables.

I don't know how to optimize query or to avoid here joining.

Could someone help me?

PS: If there is nothing to optimize I think I need to create table for calculated results and to use crons schedule.

Comment: the main reason that the joining is so slow because it looks like you dont use indexes you should also include the output of `EXPLAIN [your_query]` here

Comment: `SELECT *` should never be used with `GROUP BY`.  Think about it ... columns are returned that are not aggregated and are not aggregation keys.

Comment: Ive added index for pt_created and attached explain of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't select fields you don't need. MySQL *might* be smart enough to ignore the `SELECT *`'s in the subqueries, but I wouldn't bet on it.
2. Avoid using function calls on criteria; if pt_created is indexed, `DATE()` is going to make the query ignore the index; if pt_created isn't indexed, it should be.

   WHERE (DATE(c.pt_created) >= '2016-10-06' AND DATE(c.pt_created) <= '2016-12-14')

would be better, more efficient as:

```
c.pt_created BETWEEN '2016-10-06 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-14 23:59:59'
```

Relatedly, it's not quite clear what this is supposed to do:

```
ON DATE(`c`.`pt_created`)=DATE(`x`.`pt_created`)
```

---

What peculiar requirement resulted in that query rather than something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `pst`.`pt_created`) AS `count`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT `pst`.`pt_scanid`) AS `uniq`,
       DATE(`c`.`pt_created`) AS theDate
FROM `partners_scanstracking` AS pst
WHERE pst.pt_created BETWEEN '2016-10-06 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-14 23:59:59'
  AND pst.`pt_partner_id` = '0'
GROUP BY theDate
ORDER BY theDate ASC
```

Comment: Im joining the set of unique `pt_scanid` by each day, then i will count them and group by day

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT `pst`.`pt_scanid`) AS `uniq` - this will return unique `pt_scanid` in **this day**, but i need totally unqiue `pt_scanid` for the **whole** table.

Comment: I'd recommend doing that in a separate query.